# Integrating PayUmoney with django project

Tags: python, django, payumoney

I am new to django, i am trying to integrate payumoney with my django project. but i am unable to integrate please anyone can give me the steps of payumoney integration.

Comment: There is an integration guide on their side.

Comment: #syntonym yahh i read their documentations but i need some clear steps.

Comment: What have you tried ? What sort of "clear"steps do you need ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer  [API documentation](https://www.payumoney.com/pdf/API-Docs.pdf) ,[Integration doc](https://www.payumoney.com/pdf/PayUMoney-Technical-Integration-Document.pdf),and [website integration](https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html)

Comment: #onkar: Thank you onkar...i got detailed information from given links

Comment: @mahendrakamble then in that case, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@app.route('/flaskpayment/<cid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def flaskpayment(cid):
    try:
        with app.app_context():
                form = PaymentForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #read data from previous form 
            amount = request.form['amount']
            firstname = request.form['fname']
            email = request.form['email']
            phone = request.form['phone']

            productinfo = cid
            MERCHANT_KEY = "XXXXXXX"
            key="XXXXXXX"
            SALT = "XXXXXXXX"
            PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in/_payment"
            posted={}
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(random.randint(0,20)))
            txnid=hash_object.hexdigest()[0:24]
            hashh = ''
            posted['txnid']=txnid
            hashSequence = key+'|'+txnid+'|'+amount+'|'+productinfo+'|'+firstname+'|'+email+'||||||||||'
            posted['key']=key
            hash_string = hashSequence
            hashVarsSeq=hashSequence.split('|')
            '''for i in hashVarsSeq:
                try:
                    hash_string+=str(posted[i])
                except Exception:
                    hash_string+='''''
            hash_string+='|'
            hash_string+=SALT
            hashh=hashlib.sha512(hash_string).hexdigest().lower()

            #Payumoney required parameters
            form.key.data  = MERCHANT_KEY
            form.hash_string.data = hash_string
            form.hash.data = hashh
            form.posted.data = posted
            form.firstname.data = firstname
            form.email.data = email
            form.txnid.data = txnid
            form.amount.data = amount
            form.phone.data = phone
            #service_provider only for secure payment 
            form.service_provider.data = 'payu_paisa'
            form.productinfo.data = cid
            form.surl.data = 'https://www.yoursite.com/success/'
            form.furl.data = 'https://www.yoursite.com/failure/'

            return render_template('paymentform.html',form=form, action = PAYU_BASE_URL)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(random.randint(0,20)))
 I have error in mentioned above the line sir

Comment: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Comment: I cannot find  form = PaymentForm()
this method Sir

Answer (score 0):

here is an article you can definitely check it out for more information:-
https://makedeveasy.medium.com/payumoney-integration-with-django-rest-framework-and-javascript-19f266a6bad7